# Countable and uncountable bases of standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am reading lecture notes on bases of topological spaces, and am confused as to the countability of some bases of $\mathbb{R}$.

If we consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology, then a basis is $\mathcal{B_1} = \{\ (a,b)\ :\ a,b \in \mathbb{R}\ \}$. My lecture notes provide another example for a basis $\mathcal{B_2} = \{\ (a,b)\ :\ a<b;\ a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\ \}$, which is claimed to be countable. Why is this so?

Comment: The reason is that $\Bbb Q^2$ is countable and $\{\langle a,b\rangle:(a<b)\land (a,b\in\Bbb Q)\}\subset\Bbb Q^2$. See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this result is true because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. And the base $B_2$ is countable because its cardinal is lower than the cardinal of $\mathbb{Q}^2$ (basically there is at most one element of $B_2$ for each element $(a,b) \in\mathbb{Q}^2$), and $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is countable.